# Difference between "import" and "imports" in GJS

Tags: gjs

[gjs.guide](https://gjs.guide/extensions/overview/imports-and-modules.html) recommends writing GJS import statements like this:

```js
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
```

while most actual code that I see, and also the built-in Gnome Builder templates have this:

```js
import Gtk from 'gi://Gtk';
```

What's the difference between the two? When should I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After bumming around in the gjs repository for a while I've stumbled upon this file: [doc/ESModules.md](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/blob/4c31b77f8a509d7586a0932552d74d9896b0b080/doc/ESModules.md)

In it they refer to "imports" as the legacy way of importing modules. From what I understood from that document:

- `imports` predates `import` (it was a way of describing modules in GJS before ES actually had modules)
- `imports` gives you all `var`s from the module, while `import` only gives you things that were explicitly exported with the `export` keyword;
- so far you can use both mechanisms, but `import` should be preferred for new code.

Comment: Your self-answer is about 99% correct. Now that ESM is available, `import` should be preferred when possible, however you will have bad luck mixing the two methods. If you are writing a GNOME Shell extension, you must use legacy `imports` until all of GNOME Shell switches.

Comment: At first I thought their documentation was not up to date because `gjs.guide` is Google's first result but it turns out the up to date docs are on : https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gjs/